# С чем может быть связана проблема? Отваливаются зависимости

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал сносить проект несколько раз, в нугете обновлений нет, переодически возникает само по себе, через пару дней исправляется, опять же само. В этот раз попытался создать UnitTest, опять отвалились.

Comment: У меня такое появилось когда попытался поставить на проект .netCore nuget-пакет для .netFW4.7, всё покрылось жёлтыми значками (вообще всё, а не только то что ставил), но всё компилится и работает. Если это всего-лишь предупреждения - можно проигнорировать.

Comment: У меня было когда удалили и добавили файл депенденси

Comment: В папке C:\Users\%Username%\.nuget\packages могут лежать пакеты с траблами, как вариант можно попробовать переименовать папку и визуалка попробует перекачать пакеты...

Comment: Сделайте unload проекта, затем load обратно.